# javascript prototype write by different type

Tags: javascript

Why does this code work:

```js
var Class = new MyClass();
        
function MyClass() {}
        
var Class1 = new MyClass();
         
function Class1() {}
          
console.log(Class1.prototype == Class.prototype);

MyClass.prototype.sayName = function() {
  alert("abc");
};

Class.sayName();
```

But this one doesn't work. The system keeps telling me `sayName` is undefined but if I declare a function, the system will read it first before executing code right?

```js
function sayName() {
  alert("abc");
}

MyClass.prototype.sayName();
Class.sayName();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please put all the code in one block as you expect it to run. Best would be to put it in a snippet and show the execution you experience.

Comment: Also, please indent your code properly, it's hard to read it. There are several online tools, here is one: https://www.danstools.com/javascript-beautify/

Comment: This would have worked  MyClass.prototype.sayName = sayName

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to call a function that doesn't exist :

```
MyClass.prototype.sayName();
```

Instead, you intend to assign the previously defined function to the MyClass class:

```
MyClass.prototype.sayName = sayName;
```

Now you can call it :

```
MyClass.sayName();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block you are assigning an anonymous function to the prototype.sayName property. In the second code block, you are declaring the function but not assigning it to the prototype. The error is probably thrown when 'MyClass.protocol.sayName()' is called, since sayName is not declared in 'MyClass.protocol'

Try the following:

```js
var sayName = function() {
       alert("abc");
    }
    function sayHello() {
        alert("hello");
    }
    function MyClass() {};
    
    MyClass.prototype = {
      constructor: MyClass,
      sayName: sayName,
      sayHello: sayHello
    }

    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.sayName();
    myClass.sayHello();
    
    alert(sayHello.__proto == myClass.sayHello.__proto);
```

Comment: if I write like this. the prototype will be different. when i use console.log(sayHello.__proto__==MyClass.prototype); compare both. it will show me false.

Comment: Not sure why the protos are not the same??

Comment: it is because each function has own prototype. When u create new function system will auto created prototype.  if I no declare let a==b  mean I have 2 prototypes. that what I understood.

Comment: The proto are actually the same, see updated code snippet. Your example comparison was comparing the function to the class containing the function.